# Regex replace a comma with a backslash+comma - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

If you type this in the console, the expected string will not work

```
let a = "Grand A, 888 [Grand ref - 777]";
```

I want to replace the comma `(,)` to be backslace comma `(\,)`

```
let b = "Grand A\, 888 [Grand ref - 777]";
```

However, tried with several combination but not working.

`a.replace(/,/g, '\,');` will print `"Grand A, 888 [Grand ref - 777]"`

`a.replace(/,/g, '\\,');` will print `"Grand A\\, 888 [Grand ref - 777]"`

Comment: `a.replace(/,/g, '\\,')` is correct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But it produced with double backslash as I mentioned, it is on console.log not as the dup question

Comment: You do not have any double backslash. Read the linked thread to see why you are mistaken. It does not matter what console shows you. `"\\"` is a ``\``.